# How to play BackgroundCapableMedia with PlayTo on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime

I have in StandardStyles.xaml next code:

```
    <Style  x:Key="RootFrameStyle" TargetType="Frame">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame">
                <Grid>
                    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" />
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and in App.Xaml.cs next code in OnLaunched:

```
...
rootFrame.Style = Resources["RootFrameStyle"] as Style;
...
```

in MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
    PlayToManager playToManager = null;
        CoreDispatcher dispatcher = null;

        private void LayoutAwarePage_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (App.Player == null)
            {
                var rootGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Window.Current.Content, 0);
                App.Player = (MediaElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootGrid, 0);
                App.Player.Source = new Uri("http://myserverlink.com/mymp3file.mp3");

                App.Player.Play();
            }
        }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcher = Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
            playToManager = PlayToManager.GetForCurrentView();
            playToManager.SourceRequested += playToManager_SourceRequested;
        }

        void playToManager_SourceRequested(PlayToManager sender, PlayToSourceRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            var deferral = args.SourceRequest.GetDeferral();
            var handler = dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    args.SourceRequest.SetSource(App.Player.PlayToSource);
                    deferral.Complete();
                });
        }
```

And if I click devices in windows 8, in the list of devices for PlayTo no devices. 
And if one is to add a MediaElement in MainPage.xaml, the devices in the list. 
But I need to MediaElement was of Style File, what would you navigate to another page did not stop play music. What to do?

Comment: Is it just I have this problem?)
Has anyone done an application with background music playback while working PLay-TO

Comment: i dont know if i totally understand your question but if you wish to achieve playing music in background, it can be done and i have implemented this.Let me know if this is what your need.